# MySql - getting if the row count = 0

Tags: java, mysql, row

I am trying to check if the row count 0 is but i looked into the java docs but i found something that was getrowid but that dit not work i did not find any more ways to get the row count

```
public boolean isFriends(ProxiedPlayer inviter, ProxiedPlayer invited) {
    try {
        Statement sql = mySql.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = sql.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 1 FROM `friends` WHERE `friendinviter`='" + inviter.getName() + "' AND `invitedfriend`='" + invited.getName() + "';");
        if (resultSet == 0) {
            sql.close();
            resultSet.close();
            return false;
        }
        sql.close();
        resultSet.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

does someone have a way to check this if so please tell me

Comment: `if (resultSet == 0)`  resultSet is an Object - comparing to 0 doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you meant `if (resultSet.next() ){`

Comment: Your query will also return one row with one column.  When there are no friends, then the value will be `0` for the column in the row.

Comment: The returned `ResultSet` will never be equal to an int `0`. Use `next()` etc to actually access the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ResultSet is an object and you can not compare it to 0.
2. You can use resultset.next()
   It gives true if resultset has another object/tuple.
   It gives false if it does not have next object/tuple.
   In your case it will give false and you will know that the result set does not contain any result or row fetched.

Also you can refractor your code to

```
if (resultSet == 0) {
            sql.close();
            resultSet.close();
            return false;
        }
        sql.close();
        resultSet.close();
        return true;
```

to

```
try{
if(resultset.next())
 return true;
return false; 
}
catch(Exception e){}
finally{
   sql.close();
   resultSet.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if rowcount is zero you can do

```
if (!(resultSet.next())) { // will work as resultSet == 0

}
```

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> **boolean next()**
>    `true` if the new current row is valid; `false` if there are
>   no more rows